# How to write a recursive function that produces Gray codes

Tags: java, recursion

I am working with gray code and I got almost everything, but when the code run, like 1-bit or 2-bit it only prints out 0000 rather than 00 01 11 10.

```
class GrayCode {

     static void genGC(int n){
          if(n == 0){
               System.out.println(n);
          }
          else{
               genGC(n-1);
               genGC(n-1);
          }
     }

     public static void main(String[] args) {
          int a = 2;
          genGC(a);
     }
}
```

Comment: You only call `System.out.println(n);` if n is 0 so what do you expect?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the Gray codes of the required bit length arent just the concatenation of the Grey codes of bit length one less. [It's more complicated than that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code#Constructing_an_n-bit_Gray_code).

This seems to work - although there is an unnecessary amount of list copying - I may try to fix that in a later version.

```
/**
 * Prefix every element of the list with the string.
 *
 * @param list - The list to prefix.
 * @param prefix - The string to prefix each element.
 * @return - A new prefixed list.
 */
private List<String> prefix(List<String> list, String prefix) {
    List<String> prefixed = new ArrayList<>(list.size());
    for (String s : list) {
        prefixed.add(prefix + s);
    }
    return prefixed;
}

/**
 * Reflect(reverse) a list.
 *
 * @param list - The list to reverse.
 * @return The reversed list.
 */
private List<String> reflected(List<String> list) {
    List<String> reflected = new ArrayList<>(list.size());
    // use an ArrayList so I can reverse iterate.
    for (ListIterator<String> backwards = new ArrayList<>(list).listIterator(list.size()); backwards.hasPrevious();) {
        reflected.add(backwards.previous());

    }
    return reflected;
}

// Grey codes of one-bit numbers is (0,1).
private static final List<String> OneBit = Arrays.asList("0", "1");

public List<String> greyCodes(int bits) {
    if (bits <= 1) {
        return OneBit;
    } else {
        List<String> smaller = greyCodes(bits - 1);
        // Prefix the current list with "0"
        List<String> grey = prefix(smaller, "0");
        // and a reflected version of that list with "1"
        grey.addAll(prefix(reflected(smaller), "1"));
        return grey;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The actual recursion to generate the k<sup>th</sup> Gray code having n bits is ('||' means concatenation):

1. G (n, k) =  1 || G (n - 1, 2<sup>n</sup> - k - 1) for k ≥ 2<sup>n - 1</sup>

   G (n, k) =  0 || G (n - 1, k) for k n - 1

Using stopping conditions G (1, 0) = 0 and G (1, 1) = 1 and having 0 ≤ k ≤ 2<sup>k</sup> - 1

Note the subtraction in (2). It corresponds to the fact that the first half of the sequence of the last 4 digits is a mirror image of the second half. This is why Gray codes are sometimes called Reflected Binary Code (RBC).

If Lisp/Scheme/etc. is your thing, you could generate bit arrays with Gray codes using:

```
(defun gray (n k)
"Returns the kth Gray code of an n-bit sequence. Output is in the form of a bit array."
  (assert (< k (expt 2 n)) (n) "k cannot be higher than ~A~%" (1- (expt 2 n)))
  (cond
    ((= n 1)
      (if (zerop k) #*0 #*1))
    ((>= k (expt 2 (1- n)))
      (concatenate 'bit-vector #*1 (gray (1- n) (- (expt 2 n) k 1))))
    (t
      (concatenate 'bit-vector #*0 (gray (1- n) k)))))
```

NB. `cond` above works like `switch/case` in Java. The function above is a straightforward implementation of the recursive formula above.

If Lisp is not your thing and if recursion is not an absolute requirement for your program, you can amend your code by implementing the formula:

`gray = num ^ (num >> 1)`

Cheers,
 Paulo

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fairly simple Java recursive program that takes a positive integer n and produces n-bit Gray codes:

```
public static String swap(String s, String r, int i)
{
    i = i-1;
    String t = s.substring(0,i) + r + s.substring(i+1);
    return t;
}
```

`swap` takes a string and changes its i-1 character with another string that contains only one character.

```
public static void beckett(int n, String s)
{
    if (n == 0) return;
    beckett(n-1, s);
    System.out.println(swap(s, "1", n)); s = swap(s, "1", n);
    beckett(n-1, s);
}
```

`beckett` (in reference to one of Beckett's plays named Quad) produces the Gray codes.

```
public static void grayCodes(int n)
{
    String s = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        s += "0";
    System.out.println(s);      
    beckett(n, s);
}
```

`grayCodes` makes working with `beckett` easier (merely reduces the number of inputs).

You can test the above methods with:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    grayCodes(n);
}
```

For the sample input `3` it gives the following output:

```
000
100
010
110
001
101
011
111
```

Hope this helps.